# Spring security not invoking request mapping after authorization

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a custom login page which authenticates a user using a custom UserDetailsService bean. In the spring security DEBUG logs I see that the authentication proceeds fine and the list of granted authorities contains ROLE_USER.

As per the configuration the page should redirect to welcomePage.html which it does. But the response to welcomePage.html is the login.html page. The logs suggest that the authentication proceeded successfully.

I am using annotation driven configuration in my servlet xml file.

1. Why is the request handler for welcomePage.html not being invoked?
2. How to get the request handler to be invoked? It used to work before spring security integration. Other request handlers are also not being invoked after spring security integration.
3. As an aside how does spring security know that the security configuration should forward all requests to my servlet. There could be more servlets in the application. Does the login-page property of form-login consult web.xml for finding the appropriate handler? Why does it not consult web.xml and not find my request mapping for welcomePage.html then? I am using Spring MVC DispatcherServlet.
4. Is this related?
   http://mark.koli.ch/2010/07/spring-3-and-spring-security-setting-your-own-custom-j-spring-security-check-filter-processes-url.html

Here are the spring security logs:

```
19:03:49,645 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/welcomepage.html'; against '/**/*.css'
19:03:49,645 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/welcomepage.html'; against '/**/*.js'
19:03:49,645 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/welcomepage.html'; against '/**/*.png'
19:03:49,646 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /welcomePage.html at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistence
Filter'
19:03:49,646 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:158 - Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.secu
rity.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@afe7c13e: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@afe7c1
3e: Principal: security.V2VUserDetails@4a97111c; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authenticati
on.WebAuthenticationDetails@1c07a: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: E5639123A984EE19E0CEFCA19C37DA42; Granted Authorities: admin, ROLE_USER'
19:03:49,646 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /welcomePage.html at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
19:03:49,646 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /welcomePage.html at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthentica
tionFilter'
19:03:49,646 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /welcomePage.html at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
19:03:49,646 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /welcomePage.html at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
19:03:49,647 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /welcomePage.html at position 6 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAware
RequestFilter'
19:03:49,647 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /welcomePage.html at position 7 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFil
ter'
19:03:49,647 DEBUG AnonymousAuthenticationFilter:107 - SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springf
ramework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@afe7c13e: Principal: security.V2VUserDetails@4a97111c; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; 
Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@1c07a: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: E
5639123A984EE19E0CEFCA19C37DA42; Granted Authorities: admin, ROLE_USER'
19:03:49,647 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /welcomePage.html at position 8 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
19:03:49,647 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /welcomePage.html at position 9 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter
'
19:03:49,647 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /welcomePage.html at position 10 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor
'
19:03:49,648 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/welcomepage.html'; against '/login.html*'
19:03:49,648 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/welcomepage.html'; against '/welcomepage.html*'
19:03:49,648 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:194 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /welcomePage.html; Attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_USER')]
19:03:49,649 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:310 - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticatio
nToken@afe7c13e: Principal: security.V2VUserDetails@4a97111c; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web
.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@1c07a: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: E5639123A984EE19E0CEFCA19C37DA42; Granted Authorities: admin, R
OLE_USER
19:03:49,649 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:65 - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@4481f947, returned: 1
19:03:49,650 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:215 - Authorization successful
19:03:49,650 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:227 - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
19:03:49,651 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:323 - /welcomePage.html reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
19:03:49,660 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/web-inf/jsp/login.jsp'; against '/**/*.css'
19:03:49,660 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/web-inf/jsp/login.jsp'; against '/**/*.js'
19:03:49,661 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/web-inf/jsp/login.jsp'; against '/**/*.png'
19:03:49,661 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersis
tenceFilter'
19:03:49,661 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
19:03:49,661 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthe
nticationFilter'
19:03:49,661 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFi
lter'
19:03:49,661 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilt
er'
19:03:49,662 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp at position 6 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolder
AwareRequestFilter'
19:03:49,662 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp at position 7 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticati
onFilter'
19:03:49,662 DEBUG AnonymousAuthenticationFilter:107 - SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springf
ramework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@afe7c13e: Principal: security.V2VUserDetails@4a97111c; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; 
Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@1c07a: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: E
5639123A984EE19E0CEFCA19C37DA42; Granted Authorities: admin, ROLE_USER'
19:03:49,662 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp at position 8 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilt
er'
19:03:49,662 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp at position 9 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationF
ilter'
19:03:49,663 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp at position 10 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterc
eptor'
19:03:49,663 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:323 - /WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
19:03:49,665 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:115 - Chain processed normally
19:03:49,665 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:115 - Chain processed normally
19:03:49,665 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:97 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
19:03:49,915 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/css/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css'; against '/**/*.css'
19:03:49,916 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /css/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css has an empty filter list
19:03:49,915 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/datatables/media/css/jquery.datatables.css'; against '/**/*.css'
19:03:49,916 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /plugins/DataTables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css has an empty filter list
19:03:49,916 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/datatables/media/css/jquery.datatables_themeroller.css'; against 
'/**/*.css'
19:03:49,917 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /plugins/DataTables/media/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css has an empty filter list
19:03:49,961 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/css/redmond.custom/redmond.custom.css'; against '/**/*.css'
19:03:49,961 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js'; against '/**/*.css'
19:03:49,961 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /css/redmond.custom/redmond.custom.css has an empty filter list
19:03:49,962 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js'; against '/**/*.css'
19:03:49,962 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js'; against '/**/*.js'
19:03:49,962 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js'; against '/**/*.js'
19:03:49,962 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js has an empty filter list
19:03:49,963 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js has an empty filter list
19:03:49,970 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/jqueryui-multiselect/jquery.multiselect.css'; against '/**/*.css'
19:03:49,971 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /plugins/jqueryui-multiselect/jquery.multiselect.css has an empty filter list
19:03:49,972 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/jqueryui-multiselect/jquery.multiselect.filter.css'; against '/**
/*.css'
19:03:49,972 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/datatables/extras/tabletools/media/css/tabletools.css'; against '
/**/*.css'
19:03:49,972 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /plugins/jqueryui-multiselect/jquery.multiselect.filter.css has an empty filter list
19:03:49,973 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /plugins/DataTables/extras/TableTools/media/css/TableTools.css has an empty filter list
19:03:49,973 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/datatables/extras/tabletools/media/css/tabletools_jui.css'; again
st '/**/*.css'
19:03:49,973 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /plugins/DataTables/extras/TableTools/media/css/TableTools_JUI.css has an empty filter list
19:03:50,018 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/datatables/extras/colvis/media/css/colvis.css'; against '/**/*.cs
s'
19:03:50,019 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /plugins/DataTables/extras/ColVis/media/css/ColVis.css has an empty filter list
19:03:50,021 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/css/common.css'; against '/**/*.css'
19:03:50,021 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /css/common.css has an empty filter list
19:03:50,062 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/css/toppanel.css'; against '/**/*.css'
19:03:50,063 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /css/topPanel.css has an empty filter list
19:03:50,063 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/css/login.css'; against '/**/*.css'
19:03:50,063 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /css/login.css has an empty filter list
19:03:50,065 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/datatables/media/js/jquery.datatables.js'; against '/**/*.css'
19:03:50,065 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/datatables/media/js/jquery.datatables.js'; against '/**/*.js'
19:03:50,065 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /plugins/DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js has an empty filter list
19:03:50,066 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/datatables/extras/tabletools/media/js/tabletools.min.js'; against
 '/**/*.css'
19:03:50,067 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/datatables/extras/tabletools/media/js/tabletools.min.js'; against
 '/**/*.js'
19:03:50,067 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /plugins/DataTables/extras/TableTools/media/js/TableTools.min.js has an empty filter list
19:03:50,069 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/datatables/extras/fixedcolumns/media/js/fixedcolumns.min.js'; aga
inst '/**/*.css'
19:03:50,069 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/datatables/extras/fixedcolumns/media/js/fixedcolumns.min.js'; aga
inst '/**/*.js'
19:03:50,069 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /plugins/DataTables/extras/FixedColumns/media/js/FixedColumns.min.js has an empty filter list
19:03:50,070 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/datatables/extras/colvis/media/js/colvis.min.js'; against '/**/*.
css'
19:03:50,070 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/datatables/extras/colvis/media/js/colvis.min.js'; against '/**/*.
js'
19:03:50,071 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /plugins/DataTables/extras/ColVis/media/js/ColVis.min.js has an empty filter list
19:03:50,071 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/slidingmessage/jquery.slidingmessage.js'; against '/**/*.css'
19:03:50,072 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/slidingmessage/jquery.slidingmessage.js'; against '/**/*.js'
19:03:50,072 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /plugins/slidingmessage/jquery.slidingmessage.js has an empty filter list
19:03:50,073 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/barcode/jquery-barcode-2.0.2.min.js'; against '/**/*.css'
19:03:50,074 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/barcode/jquery-barcode-2.0.2.min.js'; against '/**/*.js'
19:03:50,074 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /plugins/barcode/jquery-barcode-2.0.2.min.js has an empty filter list
19:03:50,092 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/printarea/jquery.printarea.js'; against '/**/*.css'
19:03:50,093 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/printarea/jquery.printarea.js'; against '/**/*.js'
19:03:50,093 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /plugins/printarea/jquery.PrintArea.js has an empty filter list
19:03:50,095 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/js/common.js'; against '/**/*.css'
19:03:50,095 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/js/fnreloadajax.datatables.js'; against '/**/*.css'
19:03:50,095 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/js/common.js'; against '/**/*.js'
19:03:50,095 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /js/common.js has an empty filter list
19:03:50,095 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/js/fnreloadajax.datatables.js'; against '/**/*.js'
19:03:50,096 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /js/fnReloadAjax.dataTables.js has an empty filter list
19:03:50,096 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/js/fnstandingredraw.datatables.js'; against '/**/*.css'
19:03:50,097 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/js/fnstandingredraw.datatables.js'; against '/**/*.js'
19:03:50,097 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /js/fnStandingRedraw.dataTables.js has an empty filter list
19:03:50,098 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/jqueryui-multiselect/jquery.multiselect.min.js'; against '/**/*.c
ss'
19:03:50,098 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/jqueryui-multiselect/jquery.multiselect.min.js'; against '/**/*.j
s'
19:03:50,099 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /plugins/jqueryui-multiselect/jquery.multiselect.min.js has an empty filter list
19:03:50,100 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/jqueryui-multiselect/jquery.multiselect.filter.min.js'; against '
/**/*.css'
19:03:50,100 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/jqueryui-multiselect/jquery.multiselect.filter.min.js'; against '
/**/*.js'
19:03:50,100 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /plugins/jqueryui-multiselect/jquery.multiselect.filter.min.js has an empty filter list
19:03:50,102 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/toggleradio/toggleradio.js'; against '/**/*.css'
19:03:50,102 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/highlight/highlight.js'; against '/**/*.css'
19:03:50,102 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/toggleradio/toggleradio.js'; against '/**/*.js'
19:03:50,103 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/highlight/highlight.js'; against '/**/*.js'
19:03:50,103 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /plugins/toggleradio/toggleradio.js has an empty filter list
19:03:50,103 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /plugins/Highlight/highlight.js has an empty filter list
19:03:50,105 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/jquery-ui-timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js'; against '/**
/*.css'
19:03:50,105 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/plugins/jquery-ui-timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js'; against '/**
/*.js'
19:03:50,105 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /plugins/jquery-ui-timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js has an empty filter list
19:03:50,229 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/css/redmond.custom/images/ui-icons_6da8d5_256x240.png'; against '/**/*.cs
s'
19:03:50,229 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/css/redmond.custom/images/ui-icons_6da8d5_256x240.png'; against '/**/*.js
'
19:03:50,229 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/css/redmond.custom/images/ui-bg_glass_85_dfeffc_1x400.png'; against '/**/
*.css'
19:03:50,230 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/css/redmond.custom/images/ui-icons_6da8d5_256x240.png'; against '/**/*.pn
g'
19:03:50,230 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/css/redmond.custom/images/ui-bg_glass_85_dfeffc_1x400.png'; against '/**/
*.js'
19:03:50,230 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /css/redmond.custom/images/ui-icons_6da8d5_256x240.png has an empty filter list
19:03:50,230 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/css/redmond.custom/images/ui-bg_glass_85_dfeffc_1x400.png'; against '/**/
*.png'
19:03:50,231 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - /css/redmond.custom/images/ui-bg_glass_85_dfeffc_1x400.png has an empty filter list
```

Spring Security configuration:

```
  <http pattern="/**/*.css" security="none" />
  <http pattern="/**/*.js" security="none" />
  <http pattern="/**/*.png" security="none" />

  <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.html*" access="isAnonymous()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcomePage.html*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.html"
                default-target-url="/welcomePage.html"
                authentication-failure-url="/login.html"
                always-use-default-target="true" />
  </http>
```

Comment: Also I do not understand how is spring able to find my login.jsp page. Is it a special case. My request mapping for /login is not being invoked. It just automagically loads login.jsp from war/WEB-INF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem

I added spring security code but forgot to remove some parts of the old code which was responsible for authentication. I had an interceptor which would check for user in the session and redirect to the login page if the user was not found.

Removed the old interceptor and now the problem is fixed.